# Tutorial on OpenGL combined with OpenCV for Computer Vision

Tags: c++, opencv, opengl, computer-vision

Does anybody know a good tutorial or documentation that deals with mixing `OpenCV` and `OpenGL` in C++, related with `Computer Vision` and 3D rendering?

I want to create virtual scenarios with objects and then find `object's 3D poses` using OpenCV, so I can compare with the known OpenGL position but I didn't find much "quality" information so far. For example, I would need the intrinsic parameters of the opengl camera in order to use OpenCV for detecting objects in 3D world, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing difficult in mixing OpenGL and OpenCV. These are just two libraries, one for graphics and the other for computer vision. There is no overlap so you can just include both in your project.

Then it should be a matter of rendering some rectangle or a box (or whatever you wish to locate using OpenCV) - there are plenty of tutorials for that, and then copying the rendered data using the glReadPixels() function to client memory and passing that to OpenCV.

There is no tutorial most likely because it is so simple ...

You can just:

```cpp
void onDisplay(void* param)
{
    glClearColor(0, 1, 0, 1);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); // Make a green window.
}

...

void MyClass::MyInit(bool useCustomInit)
{
    std::string winname = "MyWnd";
    if (useCustomInit) {
        namedWindow(winname, CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
        resizeWindow(winname, 640, 480);
        auto handle = cvGetWindowHandle(winname.c_str());
        InitializeOpenGL(handle); // your custom OpenGL initialization.
    } else {
        namedWindow(winname, CV_WINDOW_NORMAL | CV_WINDOW_OPENGL);
        resizeWindow(winname, 640, 480);
    }
    void *param_value = reinterpret_cast<void*>(this); // Can e.g. do this or just use nullptr.
    setOpenGlDrawCallback(winname, onDisplay, param_value);

    // ...
}
```

If you're happy with default OpenGL window, you can use the `Init(false)`. If you want fancy bit depths and stencil buffers and whatnot, initialize OpenGL yourself using the OS' window handle. There are really really many tutorials for doing that.

Comment: Actually I am able to load images with openCV and then pass them as textures to openGL and then read the pixels from openGL and show and openCV frame. But the problem is not mixing them, is that I would like some information about how to deal with camera parameters, how can filters of textures affect to recognition, etc

Comment: Then you should probably rephrase the question. It's not entirely clear whether you want to use OpenGL for 3D rendering and call OpenCV on that, or whether you want to postprocess images using OpenGL and pass them to OpenCV or whether you want to study effects of texture interpolation filters (like a bilinear filter) on OpenCV recognition rate. If it's the last, then you probably don't need to use OpenGL at all, texture filtering works like weak lowpass filter. Just use that instead. If it's the second, then you need some tutorial on OpenGL shaders to implement the effects you want.

Comment: "There is no tutorial most likely because it is so simple" that is lame. One would think there would be many newbies tutorials if that is really the case.

Comment: Well, that's a bit unfair to say. It is really a matter of calling glTexImage2D() with some parameters taken from the OpenCV image structure. Merely a single line of code. Even the OP admits that he can do it (see his first comment). If you want a tutorial on that, ask the question on SO and let me know to fill the answer for you.

Comment: Using OpenGL requires some setup and the creation of a context. Frame buffers, depth buffers, stencil buffers, shaders, etc… need to be set up and connected with a window. The question is probably how to connect a OpenGL context with an OpenCV window …

Comment: @the-swine A quick code snippet on how to open an OpenCV `namedWindow` that has an associated depth buffer (maybe a stencil buffer and an accumulation buffer as well) would have been helpful. I didn’t find "its easy there is really nothing to explain” a helpful answer.